# Error while processing a beanshell preprocessor

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am new to the beanshell scripting.So my query might have basic syntactical issue.
I am getting "DocConnectionId" from regular expression extractor which is the number of elements in app screen. I have GetNewReferralId which the variablevalue i want to match with DocConnectionId.

I have written the below code:

```
 int DocConnectionId =        Integer.parseInt(vars.get("connectionIDWithDoc_matchNr"));
 int GetNewReferralId = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("GetNewReferral"));

 for(int i = 1;i<=DocConnectionId;i++)
 {
      if(GetNewReferralId.equals(vars.get("connectionIDWithDoc_"+i))){
           Integer.parseInt(vars.put("ConnectionWithDoc"));
           break;   
      }
}
```

But I am getting the below error in error log.

```
jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``int DocConnectionId = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("connectionIDWithDoc_matchNr")); . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation Integer.parseInt
```

Comment: What are you trying to do on this line? `Integer.parseInt(vars.put("ConnectionWithDoc"));` It doesn't make a lot of sense. `vars.put` returns void, you're parsing an int from void?

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer.parseInt(vars.put("ConnectionWithDoc"));
```

This line is wrong, and is guaranteed to generate a Integer parse exception. `vars.put` returns `void` value, so you're effectively trying to parse an integer from void, which will throw an exception.

I cant really tell from  your code, but are you trying to store the value of `i` in variable `ConenctionWithDoc`? In which case, you should do:

```
vars.put("ConnectionWithDoc", Integer.toString(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably connectionIDWithDoc_matchNr is not defined or you made a mistake in its case.

Could you show you full test plan.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not make a lot of sense, try elaborating what needs to be done so we could come up with more elegant solution in explanations.

Till that time here is a piece of advice:

1. If you add `debug();` line at the very beginning of your Beanshell script - you'll get extra debug output to [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) (console, where you launched JMeter from)
2. If you surround your code in [try/catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) block like:

   ```
   try {
       //your code here
   }
   catch (Throwable ex) {
       log.error("Error in script", ex);
   }
   ```

   you'll be able to see more readable and understandable stacktrace in *jmeter.log* file (usually being generated in the folder, you launch JMeter form)
3. Familiarize yourself with [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/) w.r.t. classes you're targeting to use. Copy-pasting from stackoverflow without understanding what does the code do can lead to undefined results

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for a little bit more detailed explanations and several real-life examples of using Beanshell in JMeter test scripts.

Comment: hmmm... `catch (Throwable ex)` is never a good idea... unless you know why you are doing that

Comment: @KirilS. It is a kludgy way to grab actual exception message because Jmeter's beanshell component tends to hide these details - The advice above should probably be bundled with a caveat to only do this temporarily, for debugging.